# Numpy: create array of elements in one array that are in a range around an element of another array

Tags: arrays, numpy, range, match, element

this is my problem:

Given:
array A has this shape: 12000,3 and 
array B this shape: 150,

The first column of A contains time values and B also contains time values, sampled with a different rate, so they don't exactly match.

Problem: 
Create an array C with the shape of 150,3 which contains rows of array A where the first column is within a time window around one of the time points in array B. The time window is defined by time 'before' and time 'after'

Solution:

It works with 1D lists using list comprehension, such as:
    C = [e for e in A if e > (B - before) 
                and e < (B + after)]

But trying this with arrays did not work.

I started simple on integer arrays trying to use logic indexing, but already this fails. Either I get all False or an error message.

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
B = np.array([1,3,5])

C = A[A in B]
C = A[A in B.any]
C = A[A == B]
```

np.select does the same.

Ideally it should look like this:

```
C = A[A > (B.any-before) and A < (B.any+after)]
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: sorry, I am a bit ill and made a mistake: please substitute D with B

Comment: or you could [edit] it. :-)

Comment: done - what a useful link :)

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to broadcast the A array so that the different of A and B can be broadcast together, and then reduce the original array so that we regain the dimension of B. It is also worth noting that multiplying two 1's together gives 1, and adding 1's and zeros also gives a 1. In addition, the boolean value of any positive integer is True.

```
A = A.reshape(A.size,1)
B = np.ravel(B)
bool_array = np.sum((A > B - before) * (A < B + after), axis=1).astype('bool')
C = A[bool_array] 
A = np.ravel(A)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it.

Comment: Hi,  A > B - before ... only compares A and B element wise. I am looking for a way that for every single element in A all elements in B are evaluated. Eg does the first element of A meet these conditions, tried with all elemens of  B:                B[0:-1]-before < A[:,1] < B[0:-1]+after.    Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.  You might need to appropriately flatten A and B.  (I edited the question so that you can do this.)  Then (A > B - before) will have shape (A.size, B.size).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this now. I have to loop through the shorter array but it is still much faster than list comprehension:

```
C_all = []
for i in range(len(B):
   #A and B must be np.arrays 
   bool_array = ((A > B - before) * (A < B + after), axis=1).astype('bool')
   C = B[bool_array]
   C_all.append(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like a problem I recently faced (while performing a stratified resampling, if anyone cares). The solution I ended up using was something like this:

EDIT: Depending on the size of your array, it may be much faster (and more pythonic) to use broadcasting, so I have included this and a small test to compare the two.

```
import scipy
import timeit
import itertools

def AinBiterative(A,B):
    M = B.shape[0]
    N = A.shape[0]

    which = scipy.arange(M)*(N-1)/M
    # which will contain which elements from A are selected by B, this is a first guess
    shift = (B >= A[:-1][which,0]).astype(int) - (B <= A[1:][which,0]).astype(int)
    while not (shift == 0).all():
        which+= shift
        shift = (B >= A[:-1][which,0]).astype(int) - (B <= A[1:][which,0]).astype(int)

    return A[which,:]

def AinBbroadcast(A,B):
    comp = A[:,0][scipy.newaxis,:] < B[:,scipy.newaxis]
    return A[comp.sum(axis=-1)-1,:]

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

Ms = scipy.power(10, range(1,5))
Ns = scipy.power(10, range(1,6))

for M, N in itertools.product(Ms, Ns):
    A = scipy.int_(N*scipy.randn(N,3))
    A[:,0] = scipy.arange(N, dtype=int)
    B = scipy.rand(M)*(N-1)
    B = scipy.sort(B)

    wrapped = wrapper(AinBiterative, A, B)
    iterative_time = timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=10)

    wrapped = wrapper(AinBbroadcast, A, B)
    broadcast_time = timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=10)

    print '{:<6d}, {:<6d}: {:1.2e} vs {:1.2e}'.format(M, N, iterative_time, broadcast_time)
```

I have assumed all of the B you are looking for are actually within the range spanned by A (hence the `N-1`) and that A and B are monotonic. A needn't be integer, neither must the times be evenly spaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy's broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to accomplish this.

```
>>> A = np.random.randn(12000, 3)
>>> B = np.random.randn(150)
>>> Ad = A[:, 0]
```

Here `Ad` is the vector containing the times from `A`. Numpy has a very powerful broadcasting,

```
Ad[:, None] - B[None, :]
```

will return a `12000 x 150` array, comparing every `A` to every `B`. This is very useful and fast if you have enough memory to hold that array. `12000 x 150` is quite small so is perfectly fine, but be aware if the dimensions grow a lot.

Thus, using the above idea of broadcasting, you can broadcast your rules to the whole *product space*:

```
>>> before = 0.001
>>> after = 0.001
>>> rule1 = (Ad[:, None] > B[None, :] - before) # 12000 x 150
>>> rule2 = (Ad[:, None] < B[None, :] + after)  # 12000 x 150
>>> mask = rule1 & rule2                        # 12000 x 150
>>> valid = mask.any(axis=1)
```

Note that `rule1` and `rule2` are dense comparisons (incredibly fast in numpy) that compare the above rule between every element of `Ad` and every element of `B`.

Valid here checks if every entry of `A` is inside **at least** 1 window of `B`. Note, you can 1-line mask without creating the temporary `rule1` and `rule2`, just wanted to make the code more readable.

```
>>> C = A[valid]
>>> C.shape, A.shape
(943, 3), (12000, 3)
```

We have filtered 943 elements from the 12000!

---

A function out of it:

```
def window_filter(A, B, before=0.001, after=0.001):
    """Returns indexes from A that are within a window of B"""
    rule1 = (A[:, None] > B[None, :] - before)
    rule2 = (A[:, None] < B[None, :] + after)
    mask = rule1 & rule2
    valid = mask.any(axis=1)
    return valid

>>> C = A[window_filter(A[:, 0], B)]
>>> C.shape, A.shape
(943, 3), (12000, 3)
```

And is also pretty fast (4ms):

```
>>> %timeit window_filter(A[:, 0], B)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.53 ms per loop
```

---

Additionally, if you want to further specify more constrains, such as `elements from A that are inside **only 1** window of B` you could replace `valid` as

```
valid = (mask.sum(axis=1) == 1)
```